# sklearn's RandomForestClassifier, how to rank the "importance" of a tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

In [sklearn's RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier), there is the concept of "feature importances", obtained via `clf.feature_importances_`. And there are the trees that made up the forest, obtained via `clf.estimators_`.

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the features. So I poked around, and basically saw that the trees (in `clf.estimators_`) were arranged randomly. An "important feature" is sometimes in the root, but otherwise in a leaf.

Is there a way to gauge the "importance of a tree"? An "important tree" is one that responded to the most training samples.

Comment: What do you mean by responded to the most training samples? Do you want to evaluate the performance of each tree individually (on the training data) with respect to some metric and attach a performance to each tree?

Comment: I thought each "weak classifier" in a random forest responded to a subset of training samples. Some trees covered more samples than others. Wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.